# Chef push jobs is not working

Tags: chef-infra

I have configured chef push jobs on server, node and workstation but when I execute **knife job status** command from my workstation, I do not get anything on output.

Could someone help me resolving this?

Regards

Comment: Chef Push Jobs has very few users so you aren't that likely to run into people with operational experience. Additionally your question is far too open-ended to comply with StackOverflow policies. I would recommend doing some basic recon yourself and then ask on the Chef Discourse list.

Comment: I tried doing all what I could do and then I raised this [question on Chef discourse](https://discourse.chef.io/t/error-during-execution-of-push-jobs/8626/2) . I am still waiting for a resourceful response from there.

Comment: As I said, not many people use Push Jobs, so you're basically on your own. You can purchase support help from Chef Software probably, but I wouldn't know the details.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the logs on your client node to see if its reporting an error. The logs are in /var/log/opscode-push-jobs-client.

Also, make sure you have added a whitelist which tells push jobs what action to perform on the given node.